# Screaming Frog Custom Extraction Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I am currently using Screaming Frog to scrape data from a website that my company is migrating to a new platform.

My XPath looks like this:

```
//div[@class="cs-settlements cell medium-5 border-right padding-large margin-tiny text-center border"]//h2

//div[@class="cs-settlements cell medium-5 border-right padding-large margin-tiny text-center border"]//div[@class="cramount"]/p
```

The elements I want to extract are repeating on the page. I only want the H2 and the p tags within these elements.

The HTML structure is like this for those specific elements

```
<div class="cs-settlements cell medium-5 border-right padding-large margin-tiny text-center border" data-equalizer-watch>
<h2>Title</h2>
<hr class="center">
<div class="cramount"><p>$109,000</p></div>
```

The data that is being returned contains way more than the innerHTML of those elements. For the H2 it returns that element and seemingly everything else on the page including inline javascript and the page schema. It does the same for the p tag. In both cases the data I want appears first, with the extra stuff appended after.

I also notice that it looks like in the returned data that those elements (h2 and p) are not properly closed even though they ARE in my HTML. Any thoughts on why this may be the case? I ran the page through the W3 Validator and there are no structural issues.

Comment: Could you share the url to actual html? And maybe also some code to see how you are using these XPath’s?

Comment: There is no code, I'm using the custom extraction feature from inside Screaming Frog. FWIW using DOM with PHP works to parse it just fine, using the same Xpath information above.  I haven't tested but I suspect that the HTML is invalid and that is what is causing Screaming Frog to fail on this.